# Learn Prolog Now! exercise solutions

Tags: prolog

Does anyone know where I can find solutions to the exercises and practical sessions to [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)? I started working through it and would to verify the answers that I devise.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've worked through them and decided to post my solutions as part of my blog post on learning Prolog. [Here's the link](http://zaemis.blogspot.com/2010/07/learning-prolog.html) for anyone else who may be self-studying and find it helpful.

Comment: The link here is working, but the link to the answers on that page is not.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another source, hope this helps ...
https://github.com/dragonwasrobot/learn-prolog-now-exercises

Answer (score 1):

Have you bought [the book](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/lpnpage.php?pageid=contact)? It seem that that's where they're hiding the answers.

Comment: I have; the book contains answers for the exercises, but nothing for the practical questions. I've worked my way through to the last lesson, and have been pondering the wisdom in posting my answers in my blog when I am finished in case someone else finds himself in the same position.