# Test prolog knowledge

Tags: prolog

I'd like to solve some online test's to see how good do i know prolog, 
maybe you could recommend any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/lpnpage.php?pageid=online

Each chapter contains a set of exercises, good luck.

Comment: and each chapter doesn't contain the answers!

Comment: @user584227: the paperback version does, just fyi. Anyway,  the solutions can be retrieved from http://www.saltcitytech.com/blogger/lpn.zip  Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940803/learn-prolog-now-exercise-solutions

Answer (score 0):

Try [Topcoder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc) or [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) or [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/classical/) or [Code Chef](http://www.codechef.com)

Comment: i believe this is what im looking for(99 TEST prolog problems): https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems/1 , half of your sites are random stuff which doesn not have prolog(SPOJ...)