# Learn Prolog now: Why answering true to the first query of exercise 1.5?

Tags: prolog

I have just started learning Prolog, and I'm wondering about the first question of this [exercise](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse3).

```
%% Suppose we are working with the following knowledge base:
wizard(ron).
hasWand(harry).
quidditchPlayer(harry).
wizard(X) :- hasBroom(X), hasWand(X).
hasBroom(X) :- quidditchPlayer(X).
```

How does Prolog respond to the following queries?

1. `wizard(ron). -> true`
2. `witch(ron). -> undefined procedure`
3. `wizard(hermione). -> false`
4. `witch(hermione). -> undefined procedure`
5. `wizard(harry). -> true`
6. `wizard(Y). -> Y = ron ; Y = harry.`
7. `witch(Y). -> undefined procedure`

Using `swipl` on Ubuntu, importing the knowledge base for this exercise, first of course trying to decipher what Prolog will returns, and finally checking by myself.

Ok pretty boring stuff until now, I have seen a few answer to these exercises over Github ([here](https://github.com/tboronczyk/LearnPrologNow), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940803/learn-prolog-now-exercise-solutions) and [there](https://github.com/dragonwasrobot/learn-prolog-now-exercises/tree/master/chapter-1)), and I don't understand  the answer to the first one: `%% 1. wizard(ron). -> true`.

First of all the interpreter is complaining about the two definition of what is a `wizard`:

```
Warning: /tmp/prolog/ex15.pl:4:
    Clauses of wizard/1 are not together in the source-file
      Earlier definition at /tmp/prolog/ex15.pl:1
      Current predicate: quidditchPlayer/1
      Use :- discontiguous wizard/1. to suppress this message
```

Secondly, when querying  I obtain:

```
?- wizard(ron).
true ;
false.
```

The way I get it, first Prolog returns the first fact from the knowledge base, then apply the rule head and find out that ron has neither a broom nor a wand.

All this leading to my question: what subtlety have I missed that makes others writing `true` as an answer to this query?

Comment: The interpreter does not really complain about the fact that there are two definitions for wizard, it complains that there are not written immediately one after another.

Comment: Furthermore something is `true` given there is *at least one path that returns `true`*.

Comment: The `exercise.pl` you point to is poorly structured. It defines `wizard(ron).`, a couple of other different facts, then `wizard(X) :- ...`.  That means the definition of `wizard` is *discontiguous* and many Prolog interpreters will ignore `wizard(X)` at this point. You need to keep all your `wizard(_)` definitions next to each other.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem One of my confusion lies also in the fact that the operator `;` stands for *or*, and giving an answer of "true or false" is slightly confusing at best. (although in that context I guess it is not "true or false", it's rather, "true" for the fact, and "false" for the rule head)

Comment: @asettouf: you should see "or" not as the "natural language" or (like in "*do you want tea or coffee*?") but as a logical or ("`wizard(ron)` holds *if* `true` or `false`."); and "*`wizard(X)` holds if `X = harry` or `X = ron`*".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good point, my mind sometimes does not work straight... Would you be so kind as to write an answer?

Comment: In addition to the excellent points raised in these comments, I would like to add `thatUsingMixedCaps` is typically `a_lot_less_readable_than` using underscores, which are therefore used in idiomatic Prolog code instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what subtlety have I missed that makes others writing true as an answer to this query?

```
`?- wizard(ron).`
true;
false
```

You have the clause (fact) `wizard(ron).` in your KB.

To make the things clearer you can write the fact also as the rule clause:

`wizard(ron) :- true.`

As you can see this is pretty redundant notation but useful in some cases as the general fact representation.

So your query can be interpreted as follows:

**Is there an `wizard` called `ron`?**

Since you have the fact `wizard(ron) :- true.`

Prolog will first unify the goal and the head. 
In your case unify is trivial comparison because no variables are in the goal and the head.

Then Prolog tries to prove body. The body is builtin predicate `true`, so you quickly get the answer - **true**.

Then pressing ';' you initiate the search for the alternative solution.
Since no (more) solutions exist for the query `wizard(ron)`, Prolog writes **false**.

The dot operator designates the clause end. So you wrongly typed dots in your examples:

`->` operator means if-then-else relation. It can be used within clause body.

For example you can write `std_member/2` as `if_member/2`

```
std_member(X, [ X | _  ]).
std_member(X, [ _ | Xs ]) :-
    std_member(X, [ _ | Xs).

if_member(X, [ Y | Xs ]) :-
    X = Y ->  true;
       if_member( X, Xs ).
```